# get content from all dbs in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have primarily  3 major tables called news,albums and videos. I want to create a facebook wall kind of page where in all the updates from all the three tables would appear sorted by posted time in descending order.

Is it possible to make this kind of call in a single query to db.

i will explain briefly my tables

news has id,title,content,timestamp
albums has id,title,albumdirectory,timestamp
videos has id,title,youtubelink,timestamp.

If not possible what would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying all three tables at the same time for this purpose will be **not a good practice**. You can create a **feed table**. and insert **reference ids** from all other tables you want i.e **(news,albums,videos)** and with the **date** of that field. Now you can query the feed table and put a **join** to other three tables on the basis of that reference id in that table and display them according to date in the feed table. I'm using this approach and this is working good for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how that data is designed. If it is all related using some shared ID, you can make a single join query to get all the data. If that data is not related, you will need to make 3 separate calls.

Answer (score 0):

If the info you want on each entity shares the same structure (i.e. id, title, timestamp) then you can do this with a UNION

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('news','-',id),title,`timestamp`
    FROM news
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT('albums','-',id),title,`timestamp`
    FROM albums
    UNION
    SELECT CONCAT('videos','-',id),title,`timestamp`
    FROM videos
) AS all_items
ORDER BY `timestamp`
```

If the id fields are unique across the database (rather than just within each table) then you can remove the CONCATs and just return the ids.